# Power Automate Embed Image

Tags: power-automate, power-platform

My goal is to embed an image under outlook via power automate. I was able to check some online guides however still having an error.

> Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Send_an_email_(V2)' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template function 'outputsoutputs' is not defined or not valid.'.

I have attached a screenshot of my flow and the function I used.

[image]

[image]

I have checked videos online. My goal is to embed an image to outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong expression in `src` of image. Try using `outputs` instead of `outputsoutputs`.

Follow below links for more information:

1. [Power Automate: Embed an image in an email](https://mohitvash.wordpress.com/2020/09/06/power-automate-embed-an-image-in-an-email/)
2. [Add images to email messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/how-to/add-images-email-messages)
3. [How to send an email with an embedded image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/power-platform/power-automate/how-to-send-email-with-embedded-image)

Comment: Hi I tried to use the 3rd option which is coming from this link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/power-platform/power-automate/how-to-send-email-with-embedded-image

however it won't show the photo just a small box with an "X" inside